# Petición ajax da error y no abre archivo php ni manda datos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un problema con una petición *Ajax*. No sé si lo estoy haciendo correctamente, el caso es que siempre lo había hecho con la librería *Jquery*, pero ahora quiero hacerlo únicamente con *Javascript*.

**Código**

```
var enviarObjeto={'titulo': 'hola','usuario': 'Pier'};
var objeto = "json_name=" + JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(enviarObjeto));
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "guardar.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
if (xhr.status == 200) {
   xhr.send(objeto);
   xhr.onload = function () {
   alert(this.responseText);
 };

alert('enviado ok');
} 
else {
    alert('error');
}
```

¿Podéis decirme qué he hecho mal? es la primera vez que lo realizo con *Javascript* y os agradecería que me digáis dónde están mis errores .

Comment: Sobre qué navegador ejecutas el ejemplo? Ten en cuenta que algunos navegadores no conocen el XMLHttpRequest. Jquery internamente busca el objeto correcto y lo devuelve para usar estas peticiones ajax

Comment: Angel gracias, ahora lo estoy probando con Chrome. Mismo problema que con Mozilla.

Comment: Sería interesante que, en caso de error, mostraras el código de estado para dar una idea de qué está fallando (404? 500? 401?). También puedes llamar directamente a la URL desde el navegador y ver qué devuelve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses para en envio de datos FormData. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo.

```
  envioAjax();
        function envioAjax() {
            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("nombre", "Jose");
            formData.append('apellido', 'Sotteccani');
            formData.append('edad', '26');
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open("post", "test.php");
            xmlHttp.send(formData);
        }
```

Este es el archivo en php que recibe los datos.

```
<?php
    $datos = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $edad = $_POST['edad'];
    echo "Los datos de usuario son: ".$datos." ".$apellido." ".$edad." ";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas enviar un objeto `Json`, prueba agregando lo siguiente:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Por otro lado, no estas enviando los valores, por ejemplo con `xhr.send({});`

[En esta URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax) hay un ejemplo similar a lo que deseas hacer.

Saludos